# Junit test for Exception

Tags: exception, junit4

I try to test my Exception JUnit and the test doesn't pass I have this error trace :

```
org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnitAndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
```

and

```
org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
```

and here is my code :

```
PatientEntityFacade pef = new PatientEntityFacade();          
Mockito.when(pef.findByNumber(5555)).thenReturn(patientEntity);        

@Rule
public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void shouldThrow() throws PatientNotFoundException
{
    thrown.expect(PatientNotFoundException.class);
    thrown.expectMessage("personalized exception no patient found");

    try {
        pef.findByNumber(5555);
    } catch (com.patient.facade.PatientNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code that belongs to that errors?

Comment: And maybe part of your build-script and used IDE?

Comment: check my last edit

Comment: I already mentiened that it shoud be throw in @Test method

Comment: and i tryed to avoid try catch , still not working @LenglBoy

Answer (score 1):

If you watn to test your `Exception`, then do it the right way.

Define when Exception should be thrown.

- in `@BeforeClass` if every Method should
- in `@Test`-method if only this Method should throw it.

Notice, that you can use `any(X.class)` if other methods got other values for it.

Don´t try-catch in unit-tests.
Catch it this way and if there is no `Exception`, the test will fail.

```
@Test(expected = PatientNotFoundException.class)
public void shouldThrow()
    pef.findByNumber(5555);
}
```